# No wi-fi adaptor found -Ubuntu -rtlwifi_new.git shows repository not found

Tags: networking, git

I have installed Ubuntu a month ago and there in settings, it shows **no wi-fi adaptor found** well on youtube I found a solution, where I needed to clone this **rtlwifi_new.git**. But when i gave the command
`sudo git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git`  It asked for the git username and password and then it showed me the error **remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git/' not found**. Couldn't find anything till now. Here is the link of youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dokG4bCF4GQ&t=176s.... Please HELP

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the Solution**
**rtl8192ce** worked for me !!! followed the instructions here [http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/#:~:text=If%20you%20just%20downloaded%20and,VIA%20SOFTWARE%20UPDATER%20AND%20REBOOT.&text=Here's%20what%20I%20did%20to,sure%20wireless%20network%20are%20enabled.](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20just%20downloaded%20and,VIA%20SOFTWARE%20UPDATER%20AND%20REBOOT.&text=Here%27s%20what%20I%20did%20to,sure%20wireless%20network%20are%20enabled.)

Answer (score 0):

that repo doesn't seem to exist. if you look in [the list of lwfinger's repos](https://github.com/lwfinger?tab=repositories) there is a mention of it in [rtl8723be](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be) but when you look at the readme of that it reccommends to

> Use the driver in the kernel, or the one in the Backports Project.

the repo you were looking for was abandoned

> The master branch of this repo is officially abandoned. If you are running a kernel newer than 5.0, use the drivers built into your kernel. That is a lot less work.
>
> If you must have these drivers with an older kernel, then google the Backports Project, download, and build their codes.
>
> If you are using a Realtek RTL8723DE, RTL8822BE, RTL8822CE, or RTL8821CE, then you need the rtw88 branch:
>
> git checkout origin/rtw88 -b rtw88
>
> Then follow the README there.
>
> DISCLAIMER: If you don't read any of this README, I will not answer to any of your issues

if you want to have a look yourself or are looking to get an older version try the [Waybackmachine link to the repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20200615040921/https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new)